# How to change the color of the text in Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps

In **Google Maps**, I need to make Text color, Background color of map configurable using simple string parameters but Based on Google Docs https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/hiding-features we can acheive this by Passing a JSON style object to your map so Is there any possibility to change the text color of city,background color of Map **without a JSON style**.

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#000000"
  },
  {
    "lightness": -55
  },
  {
    "visibility": "simplified"
  },
  {
    "weight": 2
  }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What you are doing is the way to change it. Try with some other colors as the color in the maps and the #000000 are almost same, you may not notice the changes.

Comment: @Avid sorry avid..i am not getting you

Comment: As you are using #000000 which is the hex code for color Black, you might not be able to see the exact changes that are happening. SO try with some other color and check if it is working or not.

Comment: @Avid yea avid, it will change whatever color we are mentioning but my  question is..do we have any other alternate methods to implement this

Comment: No you cannot access it directly. So all you can do is by the above mentioned method.